# mocha + mongodb wait for async result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, mocha.js

So this is my function which should insert data that i need later on:

```
const mongo = require('mongoskin');
const mochaDB = mongo.db(MONGO_URL, {});

function createTestAdmin() {
  const userData = createTestUserData();
  mochaDB.collection('users').insert(userData, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

So now my problem is, that the insert runs async and before i can acces the inserted data i have to wait until this function has completed.

**Note1**: This happens during a `before` block inside a mocha test run.

**Note2**: I am using mongoskin which is a wrapper for the mongodb client, but if there is a solution for the mongodb client, i can throw away mongoskin.

Is there a way i can wait for the db to finish the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about mongoskin, but the native client's `insert` method returns a promise that resolves when the insert has been completed.

Also, if you return a promise from Mocha's before method, mocha won't start any tests until this promise resolves (or reject).

You can hopefully refactor your code so that the before method returns the promise returned by the `insert` method.

Maybe something like:

```
function createTestAdmin() {
  const userData = createTestUserData();
  return mochaDB.collection('users').insert(userData, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
before(function() {
// other code
return createTestAdmin()
})
```

If you have more asynchronous operations inside your "before" function, you can return `Promise.all([p1, p2...])`, where `p1`, `p2` etc are each one promise for each async operation.

Comment: Thx i am going to check

Comment: so in `Promise.all([p1, p2...])`  i could replace the elements in the array with the functions that run async code, like the `createTestAdmin()`?

Comment: @Gobliins as long as these functions return the promise you need to wait for, yes :)